# java bluetooth Limited Dedicated Inquiry Access Code (LIAC)

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

We have a device that is discoverable only in Limited Inquiry Access. There is a second device with a firmware that can talk to this device. We are trying to connect to this device from a computer with a bluetooth dongle. Thus far, we tried to use BlueCove-2.1.1.SNAPSHOT jar library and the code example [from this page](http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-device-discovery/) but with LIAC instead of GIAC (General Inquiry Access). Here is the only change that we have done

```
agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.LIAC, bluetoothDeviceDiscovery);
```

Everything else is exactly the same as per the example code from the above link. For some reason, the device is not discovered.

We have no bluetooth background and we are just trying to get started here so please excuse us if it's too high level of a question for this site. Can anyone shed some light as to what has to be done to discover this device on a PC. At this point, we just need to print the address of the device. We are trying out bluecove library but we are pretty open to any library (free or commercial) that is supported on Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `DiscoveryAgent.LIAC` is fixed at 0x9E8B00, but the Bluetooth spec allows for 63 different dedicated address codes (from 0x9E8B00-0x9E8B3F).  Perhaps your device is using one of the other codes.